# Extra space on bottom of <div> with responsive background image

Tags: html, css

I've designed a new email layout for my website. it consists of three parts, header,body and footer. so 3 divs. the header background is done with an img tag cause there won't be anything on top of it. the body is a repeating thin line, and the footer as you see will have background and 4 img buttons for social networks. so it has to be background image not img but it must have a height cause as I searched A LOT! you can't control a div height by background image. but the problem is as the height is fixed, the background image will resize but the div won't, so I get background color on the extra part of the div. here's the file . any help will be appreciated. or even if you got an easier solution that would much much more appreciated. I know the coding is dirty I don't have much experience in it. keep in mind it's for an email so no hard stuff that mail clients can't handle. :D

Update : Well I decided to go with bottom padding, it almost fixes my problem Thank you.

Comment: What exactly you wanna achieve?

Comment: I wanna remove the extra space on bottom of the footer when it's scaled down.

Comment: Got It Let me create a fiddle for you

Comment: do you want to remove gray space which i marked in here? http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/392400/96e2c5fdc93bc73e3dbe076b9dae6f69

Comment: What do you mean? as long as it doesn't change the overall look I don't mind.

Comment: I decided to go with bottom padding, it almost fixes my problem Thank you for helping.

Comment: solved your problem. take a look at this file: https://www.mediafire.com/?kjs962tgsyz66lv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is The Working Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MissLand</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #Container{
                text-align: center;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vh;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            #Header{
                background: url("./h.jpg");
                min-height: 208px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                z-index: 2;
            }

            #Body{
                background: url("./b.jpg");
                max-width: 600px;
                min-height: 50px;
                width: 100%;
                float: left;
                clear: both;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                bottom: 0px;
                z-index: 0;
            }

            #Footer{
                background: url("./f.jpg");
                min-height: 380px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            #Header, #Footer{
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                background-clip: border-box; 
                width: 100%;
                float: left;
                clear: both;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Container">
            <div id="Header"></div>
            <div id="Body"></div>
            <div id="Footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the time and effort dude.

Comment: btw Can I ask a question? will you remove the media fire link? just for the privacy issues. The code is not a problem it should be seen here for the rest of ppl running to the same problem just not the pictures and stuff.

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to put the footer always in bottom position, bcause there's no content again, so that's why it makes extra space in bottom,

add this style on your footer :

```
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, but it doesn't help the way I need it to. sure it removes the gray space but it forces me to have an at least height  body which I don't want to have. see the body height changes with the content and btw that -1 is not from me :D